# GWT DockLayoutPanel with browser determining size of some subpanels?

Tags: gwt, layout

It looks like you have to specify absolute sizes of all but one subpanel. For example, from the [GWT docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels):

```
DockLayoutPanel p = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
p.addNorth(new HTML("header"), 2);
p.addSouth(new HTML("footer"), 2);
p.addWest(new HTML("navigation"), 10);
p.add(new HTML(content));
```

But I want the north panel sized by the browser. I put some text or buttons in it and I don't know exactly what size it will be, I just know it is relatively thin and at the top of the page.  And I want the content to take up the rest of the space, but no more, so there are no browser scroll bars.  Is there a way to handle this with these newer layout panels?

Right now I'm using the older panels, and I have a handler attached with `Window.addResizeHandler`, which sets the height of the main content area so that everything fits within `Window.getClientHeight`

**Update:**

Thomas suggested a `DockLayoutPanel` inside a `HeaderPanel`, but this is not working for me:

```
<g:HeaderPanel>
 <g:Label>Header top</g:Label>
 <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX'>
   <g:west size='300'>
     <g:Label>West</g:Label>
   </g:west>
   <g:center>
     <g:Label>Center</g:Label>
   </g:center>
 </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</g:HeaderPanel>
```

"Header top" is there, the rest invisible.  It looks like inner divs are getting 0 height.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this ? I'm trying to do the same kind of thing and I'vre already wasted too much time on this issue. Cheers.

Comment: I think I had to use a resize handler and manually calculate and resize things myself. I have since abandoned GWT.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wish I can do the same :)

Comment: As a matter of interest, can I ask if you moved onto another framework and if so which one? In general I find GWT useful but I feel its a touch clunky, I'd love to check out another similar toolkit.

Comment: I've found no similar toolkit. Lately, I'm learning to use Angular. I'm too inexperienced with it to recommend it, but it looks good so far. I still would like to see something like a JVM bytecode to js compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `DockLayoutPanel` (for the west and center regions, possibly the south one too if you don't want it to use its *natural height*) in a [`HeaderPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HeaderPanel.html) (for the *natural sizing* of the north region)

Comment: I will experiment with this and report back here.  `HeaderPanel` may do what I want, by itself, but at first glance it doesn't implement `ProvidesResize`, which I thought meant that it could not contain a `DockLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't implement `ProvidesResize` because it doesn't resize its header and footer widgets; but it calls setSize() on its center widget if that one implements `RequiresResize`.

Comment: This works, thanks. Now I need to propagate the height restriction to the ScrollPanel inside that content area, but if I can't figure that out that will be a different SO question...

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon. `HeaderPanel` helps me, but putting a `DockLayoutPanel` inside it is not working.  I updated the question.